# App Store not working on Public Beta of macOS 10.14 Mojave

Tags: macos, crash, mac-app-store

I installed the public beta of macOS Mojave on my MacBook Pro (I did not do a clean install, I just upgraded from High Sierra) but the App Store doesn't work. I couldn't find anything online on how to fix it, and I cannot even look for update without it.

Since there is no official support for public betas from Apple, I am hoping someone here can help.

I am attaching a full crash report with system statistics  [right here.](https://paste.ofcode.org/qPhKMNruWVvpvwQyfg4GbK)

Also here are screenshots of how the error looks: it cannot connect and then gives a crash.

Hopefully, someone here will be able to help with idea on what to do, I know I am an idiot upgrading laptop I work on to Beta software but hell, curiosity got better of me.

Any ideas are welcome, a just clean reinstall is out of the question (I have nowhere to put files at this time and I cannot lose them).

[App Not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywqKT.png)

[App Crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvLfq.png)

All the information about the system are in the code, but if needed I will post it here.

Comment: Have you used the bug reporting tool Apple put in the dock on Mojave to report this behavior? I have the public beta and ran across a problem, filed a bug report and got an answer a few days later.

Comment: Yes, I did manage to do it today after like 15 attempts ( basically that but reporting app "feedback assistant"  is crashing as well), but I didn't get any response, maybe because of its weekend. 
I wanted to know if there is a way for me to fix it without the wait, maybe a way to reinstall an app store? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Don't do a clean install, just restore from the backup you performed just before you installed the untrustworthy public beta.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't backup anything. I was kinda in the "ït will probably be alright" state of mind, so I am trying to find a solution to fix the problem at hand that I caused.